# Azure Webjobs and php.exe

Tags: php, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have a php application (*ARPReach*) installed on a **Azure VM**. I use Task Scheduler to run a *.bat* every 5 min that has this simple line of code:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php.exe" E:\Web\arp\a.php cli/auto
```

Now I want to move this php app to **Azure Website**, and I need a **similar scheduling functionality** as the above.

I got the path to php.exe **from the Kudu site** and added a Webjob (*cron.bat*) to my website with the following line:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php.exe" D:\home\site\wwwroot\a.php cli/auto
```

and it seems to work fine.

However **I'm not sure if this is the right way** to do it with Azure Webjobs / Websites. I mean are the paths going to **change after restart** or auto-scaling?

Can anyone confirm for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart or scaling will not change this path, it should not change unless Azure Websites will stop supporting php version 5.4 for some reason.

So this batch file should work fine, I would use `%ProgramFiles%` instead of `D:\Program Files (x86)`.